# Eureka - multiple services in one application

Tags: netflix-eureka

I have configured eureka-server and its working correctly. For the client side I have one application with two controllers. In the first controller I have 7 services and in the second i have one. The problem for me is when I set Eureka Client in my client app in Eureka dashboard I can only see the instance for the whole App.

The question is how to tell eureka to discover every service that I have in the application?

Comment: did you resolve the issue ?

Comment: I found that eureka discover the application and not the services. So it is okay.

Comment: ok @xmlParser (thumbup)

Answer (score 0):

I found that eureka discover the application and not the services. So it is okay.